# Referring to columns by name in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a loop in R that loops over columns in a dataframe `las_ref` for those columns where the name matches a value in a vector `las_names`.
As the original `las_ref` dataframe has rows with duplicated `incidentid` values, I am aiming to extract the most common value in each of the columns in `las_names` for each `incidentid`, produce a new column and use a join to produce a dataframe `las_ref3` with the most common values in every row.

Structure of `las_ref`

```
incidentid incident var1
001             abc   45
002             abc   NA
002              NA   78
003             def   12
004             xyz   NA
004             xyz   10
004             abc   10
```

Intended structure of `las_ref3`

```
incidentid incident var1 incident-new var1-new
001             abc   45          abc       45
002             abc   NA          abc       78
002              NA   78          abc       78
003             def   12          def       12 
004             xyz   NA          xyz       10
004             xyz   10          xyz       10
004             abs   10          xyz       10
```

Below is the loop I am trying to use.

```
las_names <- c("incident","var1")
for(i in las_names) {
  las_ref2 <- las_ref %>%
    group_by(across(c(incidentid, paste(i)))) %>%
    tally() %>%
    filter(!is.na(paste(i))) %>%
    arrange(incidentid, desc(n)) %>%
    summarize(paste(i,"-new") = first(paste(i)))
  las_ref3 <- las_ref %>%
    left_join(select(las_ref2, incidentid, paste(i,"-new")), by = c("incidentid"))
}
```

Currently there seem to be two issues that I think revolve around the use of `i` to refer to the columns `incident` and `var` in the examples above.

The first is that the `!is.na()` function is not removing the NA values in the columns referred to by `i`, although this does not produce an error.
The second, which does produce an error, is the summarise line. I get an  `unexpected '=' in` error when this line is run.

Neither issue occurs when I run the code outside of the loop, specifying column names individually - the result comes out as expected. As the dataset is fairly large, I was hoping to use the loop to avoid doing each column individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could write your loop in the following way to make it work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

las_ref <- tribble(~incidentid , ~incident, ~var1,
    "001",             "abc",   45,
    "002",             "abc",   NA,
    "002",              NA,     78,
    "003",             "def",   12,
    "004",             "xyz",   NA,
    "004",             "xyz",   10,
    "004",             "abc",   10
)

las_names <- c("incident","var1")

las_ref3 <- las_ref

for(i in las_names) {
  las_ref2 <- las_ref %>%
    group_by(across(c(incidentid, paste(i)))) %>%
    tally() %>%
    filter(!is.na(!! sym(paste(i)))) %>%
    arrange(incidentid, desc(n)) %>%
    summarize("{i}-new" := first(!! sym(paste(i))))
  las_ref3 <- las_ref3 %>%
    left_join(select(las_ref2, incidentid, !! sym(paste0(i,"-new"))), by = c("incidentid"))
}

las_ref3
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   incidentid incident  var1 `incident-new` `var1-new`
#>   <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>
#> 1 001        abc         45 abc                    45
#> 2 002        abc         NA abc                    78
#> 3 002        <NA>        78 abc                    78
#> 4 003        def         12 def                    12
#> 5 004        xyz         NA xyz                    10
#> 6 004        xyz         10 xyz                    10
#> 7 004        abc         10 xyz                    10
```

---

We can also use `purrr::map_dfc` within `mutate` together with `purrr:set_names`:

```r
las_ref %>% 
  group_by(incidentid) %>% 
  mutate(map_dfc(set_names(las_names, paste0(las_names, "-new")),
              ~ count(cur_data_all(), "{.x}" := eval(sym(.x))) %>%
                arrange(desc(n)) %>%
                slice_head() %>%
                pull(eval(sym(.x)))
  )
  )

#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#> # Groups:   incidentid [4]
#>   incidentid incident  var1 `incident-new` `var1-new`
#>   <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>
#> 1 001        abc         45 abc                    45
#> 2 002        abc         NA abc                    78
#> 3 002        <NA>        78 abc                    78
#> 4 003        def         12 def                    12
#> 5 004        xyz         NA xyz                    10
#> 6 004        xyz         10 xyz                    10
#> 7 004        abc         10 xyz                    10
```

---

I have a package on github, {dplyover}, which makes the approach above a bit simpler by using `over` and its `.names` argument:

```r
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

las_ref %>% 
  group_by(incidentid) %>% 
  mutate(over(las_names,
              ~ count(cur_data_all(), "{.x}" := eval(sym(.x))) %>%
                arrange(desc(n)) %>%
                slice_head() %>%
                pull(eval(sym(.x))),
              .names = "{x}-new")
  )

#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#> # Groups:   incidentid [4]
#>   incidentid incident  var1 `incident-new` `var1-new`
#>   <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>
#> 1 001        abc         45 abc                    45
#> 2 002        abc         NA abc                    78
#> 3 002        <NA>        78 abc                    78
#> 4 003        def         12 def                    12
#> 5 004        xyz         NA xyz                    10
#> 6 004        xyz         10 xyz                    10
#> 7 004        abc         10 xyz                    10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks, the first option worked. Is there a general rule for when paste(i) and sym(paste(i)) are used?

Comment: @Ant: To get the variable on base of a character string we need to evaluate `sym(paste(i))` either with `!!` or with `eval`. On the lefthand side of the walrus operator `:=` we can use `glue()` syntax and wrap the part to be evaluated in `{}. Finally, dplyr joins take character strings in the `by` argument so `sym` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

A version that avoids manual loops:

```
library(tidyverse)

las_ref <- tribble(~incidentid , ~incident, ~var1,
                   "001",             "abc",   45,
                   "002",             "abc",   NA,
                   "002",              NA,     78,
                   "003",             "def",   12,
                   "004",             "xyz",   NA,
                   "004",             "xyz",   10,
                   "004",             "abc",   10
)

las_ref3 <- las_ref %>% 
  group_by(incidentid) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(c(incident, var1), ~names(sort(table(.x, useNA = 'no'), decreasing = T))[1], .names = '{.col}-new' )
  )

  incidentid incident  var1 incident-new var1-new
  <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <chr>        <chr>   
1 001        abc         45 abc          45      
2 002        abc         NA abc          78      
3 002        NA          78 abc          78      
4 003        def         12 def          12      
5 004        xyz         NA xyz          10      
6 004        xyz         10 xyz          10      
7 004        abc         10 xyz          10
```